# Increasing natural height of minipage / fbox

Tags: minipage, boxes, lengths, height, fbox

I would like to define an environment encapsulated by a box where I am able to insert unspecified content (text, equations etc.), but where I can increase the natural height of the box. A minimum working example of what I am trying to do is below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}

\begin{document}

Some text...\\

\begin{boxedminipage}[c]{\textwidth}
\vspace{2mm}

Some more text... 
{\begin{center}
$\frac{a}{b}$
\end{center}}

\vspace{3mm}
\end{boxedminipage}

\end{document}
```

This can also be achieved with something like this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

Some text...\\

\noindent\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c][2\height][c]{\textwidth}
\centering
$\frac{a}{b}$
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

where the height of the minipage is set to `2\height`. But I would like to specify a certain extra height above and below the content, thus increasing the natural height of the box.

How can I achieve this? And how can I define a command such that I can execute it by writing something like

```
\begin{myboxenvironment}
Whatever input...
\end{myboxenvironment}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your first example? I don't quite get what you aim for, I fear ... For the second example, instead of `2\height`, you can also use, for example, `\dimexpr\height+10mm\relax` which would add 10mm to the natural height of the box, i.e. 5mm above and below the contents. If you want to create a custom environment, search for `\newenvironment` or `\NewDocumentEnvironment`.

Comment: I've found that the first option doen't work consistently - but your solution to the second was just what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: ... if compilation speed does not matter, you could have a look at the tcolorbox package.

Comment: @JasperHabicht What exactly does \height cover? Again, I would like a certain amount of extra white space consistently and independent of the content. However, if I do `\dimexpr\height+4mm\relax` for the expression `$a$` and `$dfrac{1}{b}$` the amount of extra white space (the 4mm) is not the same in the two situations. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `\height` here only returns the distance from the baseline to the top of the box, while `\depth` returns the distance from the baseline to the bottom to the box. You might want to try `\totalheight` instead of `\height` which returns the sum of `\height` and `\depth`.

As for the width, you might rather want to use `\linewidth` since this returns the width of the current box. This way, you would be able to use your custom environment also inside other boxes.

Finally, with the use of `\NewDocumentCommand` it is a bit simpler to place the `minipage` as argument to the `\fbox` macro without the need to use a savebox:

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myboxenvironment}{ +b }{%
    \fbox{%
        \begin{minipage}[c][\dimexpr\totalheight+4mm\relax][c]%
            {\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}%
            \begin{center}#1\end{center}%
        \end{minipage}%
    }%
}{}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{myboxenvironment}
    $2$    
\end{myboxenvironment}

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{myboxenvironment}
    $\frac{1}{2}$    
\end{myboxenvironment}

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{myboxenvironment}
    \begin{myboxenvironment}
        $\frac{1}{2}$    
    \end{myboxenvironment}
\end{myboxenvironment}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just what I was looking for - thank you!